# Como Implemento un meta tag de ads en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

1. Elemento de lista

necesito un poco de ayuda con un `<meta-tag>` que se tiene que implementar en el head, en un analytic pero tengo dudas de como se debe incluir de forma que se integre, en ruby on rails de forma correcta ya que si solo se incluye dentro del `<head>` desaparece cuando se hace un cambio de vista o una consulta.

el meta tag analitico es el siguiente:

```
     <head>
        <%= display_meta_tags %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= csp_meta_tag %>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('faviconD.png') %>

        **<!--Ads Exoclick-->
         <meta name="exoclick-site-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxx">
        <!--End Exo-->**

    </head>
```

apreciare su ayuda con esta pequeña duda.

Comment: Pero agregando `<meta>` en el layout que usas debería resolver eso, ¿o hay algún otro problema? ¿por qué dices que se desaparece? ¿haces llamadas asíncronas cuando haces un cambio de vista o una consulta? ¿estás usando algún framework js o turbolinks o algo que te refresca tu head? sería bueno que adjuntases código relevante que ayude a responderte, porque creo que no es suficiente con la información que entregas. Saludos

Comment: Hey disculpa por la falta de información @AlterLagos agrege como estoy agregando el codigo y estoy utilizando turbolink para los css3 y el script y agregue el anlytic directamente en el head